# How to set up spring source code for debugging in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I'm trying to set up the spring source code in an eclipse project so that I can step through it with the debugger.

Currently, the specific line of code I'm trying to step into is this one:

```
ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:spring.xml");
```

ApplicationContext and ClassPathXmlApplicationContext are part of org.springframework.context:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
```

Under "Java Build Path"=>"Libraries", I've specified the path to the file org.springframework.context-sources-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar for org.springframework.context-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar.

[image]

I'm using spring 3.1.3 with eclipse indigo 3.7.2.

Update:

I tried adding the *sources*.jar files to the source tab under "Debug Configurations" but eclipse is still not finding the source.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below:

```
Menu Option Run -> Debug Configurations -> Java Application 
   Provide required inputs in "main" tab
   Add source jar file in source tab
```

Press OK and run this newly created option to debug.

If running remote, then select `Remote Java Application` in debug configuration's left pane.

Comment: Hi I tried your suggestion but to no avail. I updated the original question with another screenshot.

Comment: @opike: Can you please share me the screen where it show, no source attached?

Comment: it actually is finding the spring source code now. When I first step inside the call, it says source not found for the classloader file, but they eventually it does make inside the spring source code.

Answer (score 0):

When working with maintaining a very old system I found that a specific jar file containing sources had to be downloaded for debugging purposes.
[http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/batch/spring-batch-core/{release number}](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/batch/spring-batch-core). And as mentioned in the answer above add that jar to the source tab for the Debug Configuration