# Eclipse - scroll to dependencies classes in maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have maven project with dependencies, I want to be able to view dependencies classes while viewing code
I can't drill down to class files of maven dependencies in eclipse when Ctrl+ left mouse click class name , for example `@Autowired` Spring or `@Test` of TestNG

I tried all [answers for Get source jar files attached to Eclipse for Maven-managed dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310720/get-source-jar-files-attached-to-eclipse-for-maven-managed-dependencies)

> Checked Window > Preferences > Maven and checking the "Download Artifact Sources" and "Download Artifact JavaDoc" options

Also control-clicking the project in Navigator view and choosing "Maven"-->"Download Sources"

Also with maven goal

> ```
> mvn dependency:sources
> ```

Also Maven -> Update project (and restart eclipse) after changes

But when I click on class as `@Test` or `@Autowired` I'm not redirected to class, although I can see class in relevant jar in project's Maven dependencies

I tried adding source files [manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13334766/how-to-set-up-spring-source-code-for-debugging-in-eclipse)

> Menu Option Run -> Debug Configurations -> Java Application 
>      Provide required inputs in "main" tab
>      Add source jar file in source tab

What am I missing to be able to drill down to dependency's classes?

I can see classes in Maven dependencies manually:
[image]

Comment: what eclipse version you are using.. ?

Comment: @gnanajeyam95 Neon, actually in new version I don't have this issue